# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x\sin(x)}{\cos^{3}(x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x\sin(x)}{\cos^{3}(x)}\,dx$$

I started like this:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\dfrac{x\sin(x)}{\cos^{3}(x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\dfrac{1}{\cos^{2}(x)}\cdot \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\cdot (x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(x\cdot \tan(x))\cdot (\tan'(x)) \,dx$$

How to continue ?

Answer (score 3):

We could try integration by parts, giving $$I:=\int_0^{\pi/4}x\tan x\sec^2 xdx=[x\tan^2 x]_0^{\pi/4}-\int_0^{\pi/4}(\tan x+x\sec^2 x)\tan xdx\\=\frac{\pi}{4}-I-\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^2 xdx.$$Hence$$I=\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac12[\tan x-x]_0^{\pi/4}=\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{1-\pi/4}{2}=\frac{\pi-2}{4}.$$

Comment: What's the difference with my hint, except you completely solve the problem?

Comment: Bear in mind the OP had already noticed the $\tan^\prime x$ factor, suggesting they'd thought to do parts, which is often easier said than done. In any case my IBP differs from the one you suggested (but matches what the OP seemed to have in mind), which would have taken $v=\frac12\tan^2 x+C$. If you can show in a fleshing out of your answer that it would also work, I'll try to upvote you when I get up tomorrow. Goodnight.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x\sin x}{\cos^3x}=x\tan x\sec^2x$$
then use the integration by part

Comment: Are there other way without involving sec ?I didn't learn at school about sec

Comment: @DanVaja Did you learn $\tan^\prime x=\cos^{-2}x$? If so, you could work just with powers of $\sin x,\,\cos x,\,\tan x$. (In case you're wondering, $\sec x=1/\cos x$.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Integration by parts, setting
$$u=x,\quad\mathrm d v=\tan x\,\mathrm d(\tan x).$$
You'll have to remember that the other form of the derivative of $\tan x$ is $\;1+\tan^2x$:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{x\sin x}{\cos^{3}x }\,\mathrm dx &=\tfrac12x\tan^2x\biggm\vert_0^{\pi/4}-\frac12\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^2 x\,\mathrm dx \\[-1ex]
\\&=\frac\pi8-\frac12\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(1+\tan^2 x)\,\mathrm dx+\frac12\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\mathrm d x = \frac\pi4 -\frac12\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(1+\tan^2 x)\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely headed in the right direction, with realizing that $\sec^2(x)$ is the derivative of $\tan(x)$. Your next step is going to be to use integration by parts with $u = x$ and $dv = \tan(x)\sec^2(x)\,dx$, so we get $du = 1$ and $v = \frac{1}{2}\tan^2(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new compared to other answers, just the mechanics I find useful. Notice that $$\tan'(x) \,dx = \,d \tan(x)$$ and $$\tan(x) \tan'(x) \,dx = \tan(x)\,d\tan(x) = \frac{1}{2} \,d \tan^2{x}$$ That is your integral is in fact

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}x\,d \tan^2{x}$$

Now continue integrating by parts.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution.

Observe that:
\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2\cos^2 x}\right)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x\sin(x)}{\cos^{3}(x)}\,dx&=\left[\frac{x}{2\cos^2 x}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\Big[\tan x\Big]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{\pi-2}{4}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of rewriting it:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}x\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}dx&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^x\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}dtdx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_t^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3x}dxdt\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\left(1-\frac12\sec^2 t\right)dt
\end{align}